# Display Tag pdf export is not downloading

Tags: java, jsp, struts, displaytag

i'm using Display tag in my struts application.. Data is displaying and everything is fine but PDF and all other file Export is not working means its not downloading any files... simple top left `No back link` is displaying... some times its working sometimes its not working please help me...

```
.
<display:table export="true" name="requestScope.prolistdata" 
               cellpadding="2" ellspacing="2" 
               size="20" 
               requestURI="/GetBatchdisplay.do"
               pagesize="20" frame="1">

<display:column property="pro_empname" title="Employeename" sortable="true"style="color:#0B1D10" />
     .//other properties
     .
    <display:setProperty name="export.pdf.filename" value="MonthReport.pdf" />
    <display:setProperty name="export.pdf" value="true" />
    <display:setProperty name="export.excel.filename" value="MonthReport.xls" />
    <display:setProperty name="export.excel" value="true" />
    <display:setProperty name="export.csv.filename" value="MonthReport.csv" />
    <display:setProperty name="export.csv" value="true" />
    <display:setProperty name="export.xml.filename" value="MonthReport.xml" />
    <display:setProperty name="export.xml" value="true" />
</display:table>
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: show me your display tag properties file.

Answer (score 2):

Add it your **displaytag.properties** file

```
export.types=csv excel xml pdf
export.excel=true
export.csv=true
export.xml=true
export.pdf=true
export.pdf.class=org.displaytag.export.DefaultPdfExportView
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation, nothing would export and only a blank page appeared, then I changed the `name="requestScope.prolistdata"` to `name="sessionScope.prolistdata"` and it worked.

Here is another solution that also fixed the problem.

Before displaying the table in my JSP I had this code to see if anything was in the list:

```
<c:if test="${requestScope.sizeOfList > '0'}">
    <display:table uid="batchAdd"  export="true" name="sessionScope.MY_LIST" requestURI="batchLoadTestsErrorsList.do">
      <display:setProperty name="basic.msg.empty_list" value= "" /> ...
```

I was also able to fix the problem by changing the

```
="${requestScope.sizeOfList > '0'
="${requestScope.sizeOfList != '0'
```

I am not sure why the `!=` worked but both solutions enabled me to export my data correctly.